# Header not touching top of screen

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a header on my page at the very top of the screen and extends across the entire screen. It is rendered as a rails partial. Whenever there is anything in the body of the page, the header gets pulled down and is no longer touching the top of the page. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this. It works fine when there is nothing in the body of the page.

Here is the css

```
html{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #Dee0D5;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navwrap{
 width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0; 
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
  height:50px;
    float: left;
    padding: none;
    background-color: #859797;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;


    ul{
       list-style: none;

       li{
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
       }
    }
}


#wrapper {

    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    height:auto;
}

#footer{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #999999;
       li{
        display:inline;
        list-style-type:none;
        float:left;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
       }

}
```

Here is the application html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div id='wrapper'>

<%= yield %>

<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the header html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id='navwrap'>
    <ul id='nav-list'>
    <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'About', '#' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Projects', '#' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Blog', '#' %></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm sure I am just overlooking something simple, but its driving me nuts!

Comment: first: get your units straight - standardize on a unit type (% / em / px ) and proceed from there

Comment: sorry, should have seen that before I posted it. I am using px for everything, I changed some stuff around trying to fix it from someone else advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding: none;` is not valid value for `padding` attribute.

try `padding:0` instead of it

```
body{
    background-color: #Dee0D5;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, didn't fix it though =/

Comment: it seems that you are using `sass` instead of `css`. you can try with `*{ margin:0;padding:0}`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding-top to -5px? I believe 5px is the default margin.

Comment: setting `-5px` doesn't reset the padding. it will set the negative padding. why not `padding-top:0px` ?

Comment: Hm. I know that with mine by default the header I have spanning the whole top 10% of the page wouldn't go on the last 5px of each edge. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `<ul>` element might have a default margin and/or padding, if I remember right - try making it have margin: 0;
Also, your `<li>` CSS rule seems to be nested inside of the `<ul>` style rule.

Comment: I'm using SASS so the nested li is not an issue. both of those are nested inside of the #nav class. margin-0 on the ul did not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you try `<ul>` margin: 0;  ?