# Header 'div' not aligned exactly to the top of screen (Simple but frustrating)

Tags: html, css, sass

I am simply adding a header navbar to an html page.But the problem is its not aligned exactly to the top.There is a small gap between the browser and the navbar.I found a solution as setting margin:0;,but the issue I have is it will only work if I code it as by selecting the whole div... like

`*{ margin:0;}`

why is that so ?

I found this solution  in another stackoverflow question but I cant comment and ask because I have low repuation.He is stating its because of SASS.But how is my code becoming sass because I was using normal simple procedure for CSS coding.

Linked soultion question.(Please check the comments in correct selected question) 
[Header not touching top of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204059/header-not-touching-top-of-screen)

My code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      * {
        margin:0;
      }

      .new {
        width:100%;
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div class="new">New Website</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using ?, its working perfectly on chrome

Comment: Its working fine for me, i am not sure which browser your are trying in.. try to put padding:0; in *{} as well.

Comment: @sam@sufyan my code  containing padding:0 works perfectly if executed.I was enquiring why such a declaration is needed and why only when declared under *{} it works.

Comment: Oh! okay.. so probably the below answers would have cleared your doubt. different browsers possess different margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browser have set user agent stylesheet at "body" tag

For Chrome: body have margin: 8; on body tag, so you will get a small gap between navbar.

You can set

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Will solve your problem.

http://jsbin.com/luqoruqewa/edit?html,output

Comment: That was much better explanation.But do you have any idea why the hell he mentioned sass in the answer explanation? (in my linked question)It made me really frustated..

Comment: You can see in question section `#nav` have a child `ul` & `li`, it show that Michael is using `SASS` for his style.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the `margin: 0;` on the div. Put it on the body or html tag. Like so:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Don't forget that you can style the html and body tags too! Making them `height: 100%;` might be of use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

* is the universal selector. It targets all elements. When you state:

```
* {margin: 0}
```

You're removing the margin from every element on the page. That works in this case, but it will have side effects that you probably won't want on a page with more content.

Your browser is adding some padding to the body element. As amoyer pointed out, set the body margin to zero and you should be fine.